# Custom activities, scripts or project in TFS build process workflow?

Tags: tfs, build

Currently I'm in the progress of updating TFS 2012 to 2013. My plan is to use the default build process template and stick to it, if possible. The existing build definitions use the old TFS method with TFSBuild.proj files. In thse proj files everything happens. Initializing the solution directory, build, clean, run unit test, drop files, etc. Compared to the 2013 build process template this is incorrect, since the workflow has activities for build, clean, run tests, drop files, etc. As well it seems that the targets file used in the TFSBuild.proj files is of a previous TFS version and hasn't been updated to a 2013 version.

The problem is that besides the build, clean, run test an drop files activities there are other activities needed. Version numbers are changed in certain files, obfuscation for dlls, check procedures if the source doesn't contain any unwanted files, zipping of pdb files, etc.

Of course it is possible to execute these tasks/activities with PowerShell scripts. On the other hand working with tasks in the a project file also seems logical. My concern with performing extra tasks in a project files is that TFS is running the activities for test, dropping files, etc. after calling the MSBuild activity.

Can someone point me in the right direction? Do I need custom developed activities that I can use in the build process template? Or is working with PowerShell scripts best practice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you've answered your own question! Poweshell is the way forward!

I would say that modifying the XAML and writing a custom activity should only be considered if powershell isn't working for you, or if your scripts are becoming so big and difficult to debug that it makes sense to turn them in to code. As you mention, some of these tasks will need to be performed well after the MSbuild activity has completed so that's not going to work.

It looks like you want to do some fairly simple steps at defined points in the process and the powershell extensibility points are perfect for this.

A simple script for versioning in the pre-build step. Checking the source for unwanted files could happen here as well.

The obfuscation, zipping and copying stuff can happen post test.

From a Maintainability point of view, I would say that powershell has a much bigger user base than Windows Workflow and MSBuild so that's another advantage to this approach.

Comment: +1. Developing Custom Activities is difficult - I've done way too much of it by now - and the new TFS2013 template's extension points are meant to do exactly what you want.